# Oracle Update Table from Query Results (Not From Another Table)

Tags: sql

I have the following query results:

```
orclid13 | casenm | (adultfn||''||adultln)

123      |12345   | jane doe
124      |45645   | john doe
etc..
```

I have another table called Cases with the following columns:

```
casenm | matter_name
```

I want to copy the names from the  (adultfn||''||adultln) results column and populate it in the matter_name column in the Cases table and have it be joined by casenm and look like this.

```
casenm | matter_name

95522  |
74555  |
12345  | jane doe
45645  | john doe
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
update cases 
    set matter_name = (select col3
                       from (<your query here>) q
                       where q.casenm = cases.casenm
                      );
```

Note that this will set non-matching values to `null`, which seems consistent with your question.

Comment: Thanks @gordon linoff.  I'm going to do this from 4 different tables.  So if I update Cases from one table, then I update Cases from the second table, the update from the first table will be erased?

Comment: @belmer01 . . . The most recent update will be the one in the final result.  However, multiple updates have nothing to do with this question.  You might want to ask a new question with a more appropriate explanation.